# Will changing app name in iOS app store affect/reset app ranking?

Tags: ios, appstore, ranking

I want to change the name of my app but was wondering if that would change/affect/reset the ranking it already has. Anyone know?

Answer (score 4):

There should be three names of your app:

1. Bundle Identifier - this is the main ID
2. Bundle Display Name - this is displayed in iPhone
3. App Name - this is probably the one in the iTunes/App Store

I believe you can change the App Name during uploading and update (with the updated Bundle Display Name) and if you don't change the Bundle Identifier all reviews and rankings should remain the same. Users will also automatically receive this update. This is most likely dependent on Apple approval after the update.

Hopefully this is still valid with the App Store changes.

---

Also I have seen this many times as a user.